# Declaring static variable in jquery

Tags: jquery, variables, static

Kindly guide me regarding declaring static variable in the following program.
I want to increment value of the static variable lists.counter with click of button.
But its not working.

```
 <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="finalspecific2_list._Default" %>


   <asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function lists() {

        var list = $('#myList li:gt(0)');


        list.hide();
        lists.counter = 0;
        var username = $("#<%= uname.ClientID %>").val();
        var pwd = $("#<%= pwd.ClientID %>").val();


        $("#<%= Login.ClientID %>").click(function () {


            lists.counter++;


            alert(lists.counter);
            lists.counter++;


        });




        $("#<%= Button1.ClientID %>").click(function () {

            {

                    alert(lists.counter);



                    }




                });
    });



  </script>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">




<asp:Button ID="Login" runat="server" Text="Login" />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Login" />





</ul>





</asp:Content>
```

lists.counter should increase when any of the button is clicked and should increament for the subsequent clicks. 
Kindly guide in this matter.

Comment: On every refresh, counter will not be incremented for sure.

Comment: It should work the way you have it: http://jsbin.com/ebesad Note that you're creating a property on the `lists` function, which is valid but not necessary for what you're doing.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a closure here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // The actual counter is contained in the counter closure.
    // You can create new independent counters by simply assigning 
    // the function to a new variable
    function makeCounter() {
        var count = 0;
        return function() {
            count++;
            return count;
        };
    };

    // This variable contains a counter instance
    // The counter is shared among all calls regardless of the caller
    var counter = makeCounter();

    // The handler is bound to multiple buttons separated by commas
    $("#button, #another_button, #yet_another_button").click(function () {
       var i = counter();
       console.log("The counter now is at " + i);

       // Probably update your counter element
       // $("#counter").text(i);
    });
});​
```

You can find the code in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/zGeQA/6/) fiddle.

If you're interested, you can read more about closures [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures).

**Update:** [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zGeQA/15/) uses multiple buttons sharing the same counter.

Comment: Dear Sammy,thanks for your help. But my code has different requirements. There are two click function in code using same variable and this variable should increase if any button is pressed. That is the scope of the variable should be in both function and not limited to any one function.

Comment: In fact, then my approach is perfect for your needs :). The effect of the closure is, that it captures the counter value over any amount of invocations. Any time you call `counter()`, you get an increased `counter` value regardless of the caller function. I'll update the fiddle accordingly so you can have another look :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `lists.Counter` with `this.Counter` and check if it works

or try this -

```
<input id="button" type="button" value="button" />

var counter = 0;

$("#button").click(function () {
   console.log(counter++);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AxD7c/

Comment: What he has should work, this just makes it a `var` rather than a  property of the function.

Comment: Dear Dipaks, Kindly suggest the solution for the modified question.

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
 var count = 1;
    $('#button').click(function() {
        $('#counter').text(count++);
    });
});

Answer (score 0):

While declaring variables in JQuery, please don't use DOT in between, instead you can use camel format to differentiate two words, so `list.counter` should be `listCounter`

Changed code :

```
$(document).ready(function lists() {

    listsCounter = 0;

    $("#<%= Login.ClientID %>").click(function () {

        listsCounter++;

    });

});
```

Comment: Dear Subhajit, thanks for your help but in our code there is one variable common to two function and this variable should increase in both function, in short there is requirement of static variable if possible kindly guide regarding declaring static variable which satisfy our code's requirement. Thanks!!!!!